# Stream is not writable when using Named Pipes and IPC .net

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, ipc

I have a VB Windows forms application which creates a `NamedPipeServerStream`, i also have a C# Console application which creates a `NamedPipeClientStream`, i want to perform IPC between the 2,

The connections are establishing but i keep encountering an error when trying to pass data from the pipeclient to the pipeserver, the error i get is "the stream is not writable"

the error happens when this line is executed in the pipeclient
*formatter.Serialize(namedPipeClient, customerinfo);*

i have debugged extensively and cannot see what is happening

here is my code:

**PipeServer VB**

```vb
 Using namedPipeServer As New NamedPipeServerStream("TAPIPIPE")
            namedPipeServer.WaitForConnection()

            Dim formatter As IFormatter = New BinaryFormatter
            Dim customerinfo As New customer
            customerinfo = DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(namedPipeServer), customer)
            If Not IsNothing(customerinfo) Then
                MsgBox(customerinfo.phone)
                MsgBox(customerinfo.method)
            End If
            'namedPipeServer.WriteByte(
            'Dim byteFromClient As Integer = namedPipeServer.ReadByte()
            MsgBox("Message received from client")
        End Using
```

**PipeClient C#**

```cs
class Handler
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            //SetProperties(args);
            using (NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".","TAPIPIPE",PipeDirection.In))
            {
                string[] seperators = new string[] { "/" };
                string[] customerparams = args[0].Split(seperators,StringSplitOptions.None);
                int pcount = customerparams.Length;
                Customer customerinfo = new Customer();
                customerinfo.PhoneNumber = customerparams[1];
                customerinfo.Method = customerparams[0];
                Console.Write("Attempting to connect to pipe ");
                namedPipeClient.Connect();
               // Stream str = new MemoryStream();
               // IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                //formatter.Serialize(str, customerinfo);  
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to pipe");
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                try
                {
                      formatter.Serialize(namedPipeClient, customerinfo);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
                }


            }
            Console.WriteLine("Enter to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        [Serializable]
         public class Customer
        {
            string method;
            public string Method
            {
                get { return method; }
                set
                {
                    method = value;
                }
            }

            string phoneNumber;
            public string PhoneNumber
            {
                get { return phoneNumber; }
                set
                {
                    phoneNumber = value;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You should include any relevant error or logging messages, including any stacktraces.

Comment: Possible typo?  You are writing to a stream defined  with `PipeDirection.In`, try ``PipeDirection.InOut`.

Comment: you are correct, thanks :)